# Intellij Idea git aliases

Tags: git, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have define few aliases in git. How can i using it in Intellij Idea 13.1?

For example:

*file*: **common-configuration**

```
[alias]

new-my-branch = !sh -c 'DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d) && BRANCH_NAME=\"my_super_branch/\"$0\"_\"$DATE && echo $BRANCH_NAME && git checkout -b $BRANCH_NAME && git push-upstream'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolve it that: change the terminal in Intellij Idea to

```
"P:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

(CTRL+ALT+S -> Terminal -> past in Shell path: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i)

In your local directory (e.g C:\Users\john smith)

1. create .gitconfig
2. open file and add:

   [alias]

   new-my-branch = !sh -c 'DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d) && BRANCH_NAME=\"my_super_branch/\"$0\"_\"$DATE && echo $BRANCH_NAME && git checkout -b $BRANCH_NAME && git push-upstream'
3. open new terminal in Intellij Idea and write:

   git new-m[tab]

And you can see alias from auto-complete: git new-my-branch

Comment: For my case, the same worked, but git aliases were failing, so I had to add "--login -i" which solved the issue. Thanks!